# What is the best protocol for uploading images in batch via FTP?

Tags: media

What is the best protocol for uploading images in batch via FTP?

Let's say my website has 3 images.

Original size is 1000x1000

I upload all images via backend as "image upload".

Later on, I want to substitute all 1000x1000 images with identical images with same name but at size 400x400.

Curious as to what is the best workflow for Drupal for this scenario.

Comment: You have multiple questions here (how to upload batch images, whether to upload images in separate folders); on *Drupal Answers*, you need to stick to one question per post.  Also, why would you upload lower resolution versions later?  Upload the highest resolution needed at the beginning, and let Drupal's image styles handle any required downsizing.

Comment: Patrick, let's say I upload an image that's 5000 pixels wide and weights 10 megs, and I choose my image style size as 400 pixels (reducing image size to 100kb), will the browser render the 10 meg version or the 100kb one? I've always wondered about that...

Comment: The browser will render whatever you configure in Drupal-- you can choose to show whatever image style (including "original") you like. You can mix and match styles using views, display suite, panels, or many other modules.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to substitute all 1000x1000 images **with identical images**
>   with same name but at size 400x400.

Since they are identical, simply use image styles. Create an image style of 400x400 and assign it to your content type's image field OR in your image field settings in a [View](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

Watch: [How to apply image styles in Drupal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sP13afNRpjE)

Comment: Yes, but with image styles, the size of the file remains the same on the server right? I'm looking at 5 gigs of images for this particular case...

Comment: @BrunoVincent in that case, find them in the `/sites/all/default/files` folder. Have the 400 x 400 be the same name and override them via SFTP upload.